# After mining (incomplete synchronized blockchain) and get 15 ether I loose everything

Tags: mining, ether

I'm pretty sure that what happened to me was an exception or a bug or certainly innexperience over Ethereum. I will establish all the facts in order to find what happened or at least an explanation.

Rigth now I know that was impossible to mine 15 ethers in less than 48hs with CPU. But I also know that I saw (I even have screenshots) with my own eyes those 15 ethers in my wallet, until I get an error with Eth Wallet and everything goes bad :)

At first my wallet started with 0 ethers and geth started from scracth to synchronize blockchain.

My question is very simple. What happened? I know that was impossible to get that amount of ether in so few hours, but how is possible that I saw those ethers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not enough that you have mined a block you have also to compete with other miners mining the same block. If two or more miners have mined the same block then Ethereum uses a protocol called [GHOST](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Design-Rationale#uncle-incentivization) to determine which block will be in the blockchain.

It is a pretty common ocurrence that recent blocks are replaced by new ones. It is called chain reorganization. That is one of the reasons to require several block as confirmation to accept a transaction as correctly executed.

Also in order to solo mine you need the blockchain fully synchronized since each block includes the hash of the previous block. If you do not have the more recent block then you can't create a valid block that other miners will trust.

But if you mine in a pool you are able to mine without downloading the whole blockchain.

Comment: So even if I have seen my ether account increased it dosen't mean that this amount is confirmed?

Comment: If other miners have propagated their block faster, or have constructed a longer chain without your block then your block will be discarded and your rewards will not be credited.